# npm showing severity vulnerabilities Laravel in ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: laravel, npm

running command `npm install laravel-mix cross-env --save-dev` from web/themes/custom/cp_bootstrap4 directory npm showing severity vulnerabilities Laravel in ubuntu 18.04 LTS

```
added 744 packages from 474 contributors and audited 745 packages in 90.492s
found 1 moderate severity vulnerability
```

I have tried commands

```
1. npm audit fix 
2. npm audit fix --force
```

but 1 severity vulnerabilities not solved.

Output of above command

```
npm audit security report
Manual Review
Some vulnerabilities require your attention to resolve                                                               
Moderate       file-type vulnerable to Infinite Loop via malformed MKV file
Package        file-type
Patched in     >=16.5.4
Dependency of  laravel-mix [dev]
Path           laravel-mix > imagemin > file-type
```

my sub-theme package.json

```
{
  "name": "cp_bootstrap4",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "[Bootstrap 4](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap4) subtheme.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "laravel-mix": "^6.0.49"
  }
}
```

Please suggest me to resolve this issue!

Comment: Some would argue that since this is a dev dependency and it's of moderate severity it might not be worth the effort to fix it since the only person that can exploit it is you or another developer. At any rate this is on a dependency of laravel-mix so it probably isn't your job to fix it rather than report it to them (assuming you are using the latest version of laravel-mix and are able to reproduce the issue)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding to your package.json an override that means it will replace a package in your dependency tree with another version.

The package that has vulnerabilities is file-type, but npm says that you have to update the dependent-package (package>dependent-package>package-with-vulnerabilities), so you will have to update imagemin.

It seems that laravel-mix have not fix this issue, but the solution all ready exist.
Check this URL: https://snyk.io/test/npm/laravel-mix/6.0.20#SNYK-JS-FILETYPE-2958042

Try with this code on your package.json

```
{
    "name": "cp_bootstrap4",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "[Bootstrap 4](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap4) subtheme.",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "devDependencies": {
        "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.49"
    },
    "overrides": {
        "laravel-mix": {
            "imagemin": "^8.0.1"
        }
    }
}
```